# my redirection button don't redirect to the page that I build but to a 404 error page

Tags: html

I am facing an issue with redirection in my HTML web development project. I have created a homepage with buttons for user registration and login. However, when I click on these buttons, instead of redirecting to the intended pages (registration.html and login.html), I encounter a '404 Not Found' error. I have checked the paths and ensured that the pages exist in the same directory. Additionally, I've placed the redirection code in the onclick attribute of the buttons. Despite these efforts, the redirection is not working as expected. I'm seeking assistance to troubleshoot and resolve this redirection problem.
here the code of my main page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Page d'Accueil</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #392439;
            color: #fff;
        }

        header {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #92439;
            z-index: 1000;
            width: 100%;
        }

        header a {
            display: block;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 400px;
            height: auto;
            margin-top: -75px;
        }

        main {
            padding-top: 60px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 36px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-family: 'Gilroy Extra Bold', sans-serif;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .banner {
            width: 20.333%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            top: 30%;
        }

        .banner-background {
            background-color: #392439;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 15%;
            border-radius: 15px;
        }

        .gender-buttons {
            position: absolute;
            top: 115%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            display: flex;
            gap: 40px;
        }

        .gender-buttons button {
            padding: 15px 20px;
            font-size: 25px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .button-homme {
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .button-femme {
            background-color: hotpink;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .buttons {
            position: absolute;
            top: 8%;
            left: 95%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            text-align: center;
        }

        button {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .image-section {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            margin-top: 250px;
        }

        .image-container {
            width: 19%;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .image-container img {
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .image-text {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 15px; /* Ajustez la position verticale du texte par rapport à l'image */
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            color: #fff; /* Ajustez la couleur du texte si nécessaire */
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); /* Fond semi-transparent pour améliorer la lisibilité */
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 40px; /* Ajustez la taille du texte */
        }
    /* Ajoutez cette partie à la fin de votre section style */

.additional-banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%; /* Ajustez la position verticale de la nouvelle bannière */
    left: 35%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 20.333%; /* 1/3 de la largeur de la page */
}

.additional-banner .banner-background {
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 250%;
    padding-top: 15%; /* Ajoutez cette propriété ici */
    border-radius: 15px; /* Ajoutez cette propriété ici */
}

.realistic-animated-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 40%;
    transform: translate(60%, -43%);
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
}

.realistic-animated-buttons button {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.button-realiste {
    background-color: mediumvioletred;
    color: #000000;
}

.button-anime {
    background-color: mediumvioletred;
    color: #000000;
}

}

};
    width:100%;
    padding-top:15%
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.realistic-animated-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
}

.realistic-animated-buttons button {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.button-realiste {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}

.button-anime {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
}

.realistic-animated-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2000%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    gap: 40px;
}

.realistic-animated-buttons button {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.button-realiste {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}

.button-anime {
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="mon_logo.png" alt="Mon Logo">
        </a>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h1>Découvrez la magie de l'IA !</h1>
    </main>

    <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-background">
            <div class="gender-buttons">
                <button class="button-homme" onclick="alert('Homme')">Homme</button>
                <button class="button-femme" onclick="alert('Femme')">Femme</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button onclick="window.location.href='inscription.html'">S'inscrire</button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='connexion.html'">Se connecter</button>
    </div>

    <div class="image-section">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image1.png" alt="Image 1">
            <div class="image-text">Alice  ,   25 ans</div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image2.png" alt="Image 2">
            <div class="image-text">Rebecca  52 ans</div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image3.png" alt="Image 3">
            <div class="image-text">Youna  18 ans</div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="image4.png" alt="Image 4">
            <div class="image-text">Vicky  ,   25 ans</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Ajoutez cette partie à la fin de votre fichier body -->

<div class="additional-banner">
    <div class="banner-background">
        <div class="realistic-animated-buttons">
            <button class="button-realiste" onclick="alert('Réaliste')">Réaliste</button>
            <button class="button-anime" onclick="alert('Animé')">Animé</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
 </html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inscription</title>
    <!-- Ajoutez vos styles CSS ici si nécessaire -->
</head>
<body>
</html>
```

This is the code of the registration page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inscription</title>
    <!-- Ajoutez vos styles CSS ici si nécessaire -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Inscription</h1>

    <!-- Formulaire d'inscription traditionnelle -->
    <form id="traditional-signup-form">
        <!-- Ajoutez les champs nécessaires (nom, prénom, email, mot de passe, etc.) -->
        <label for="fname">Prénom:</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>

        <label for="lname">Nom:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

        <label for="password">Mot de passe:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="submitTraditionalSignup()">S'inscrire</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Bouton pour s'inscrire avec Google -->
    <button type="button" onclick="signupWithGoogle()">S'inscrire avec Google</button>

    <script>
        function submitTraditionalSignup() {
            // Logique pour traiter l'inscription traditionnelle
            // Vous pouvez utiliser JavaScript ou envoyer le formulaire à un serveur via AJAX
            alert("Inscription traditionnelle en cours...");
        }

        function signupWithGoogle() {
            // Logique pour s'inscrire avec Google
            // Redirigez l'utilisateur vers le flux d'authentification Google
            alert("Redirection vers l'inscription avec Google...");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the connection page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Connexion</title>
    <!-- Ajoutez vos styles CSS ici si nécessaire -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Connexion</h1>

    <!-- Formulaire de connexion -->
    <form id="login-form">
        <!-- Ajoutez les champs nécessaires (email, mot de passe, etc.) -->
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

        <label for="password">Mot de passe:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="submitLoginForm()">Se connecter</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Bouton pour se connecter avec Google -->
    <button type="button" onclick="loginWithGoogle()">Se connecter avec Google</button>

    <script>
        function submitLoginForm() {
            // Logique pour traiter la connexion
            // Vous pouvez utiliser JavaScript ou envoyer le formulaire à un serveur via AJAX
            alert("Connexion en cours...");
        }

        function loginWithGoogle() {
            // Logique pour se connecter avec Google
            // Redirigez l'utilisateur vers le flux d'authentification Google
            alert("Redirection vers la connexion avec Google...");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not _misuse_ buttons for simple "linking" functionality. Use the _appropriate_ HTML element - `a` with a `href` attribute - and _format_ it to look like a button, if required.

Comment: _"when I click on these buttons, instead of redirecting to the intended pages (registration.html and login.html)"_ - I don't even see where in your code you would be referring to either of those URLs, I can't find `registration.html` or `login.html` anywhere in your code ...?

Comment: (Instead I do see `inscription.html` and `connexion.html`, which presumably are the French versions of "registration" and "login"?)

Comment: To add to @CBroe comment about the buttons, your registration & connections pages both have buttons that submit forms and you have given them type="button" when they should be type="submit". <button type="button"> should only be used for buttons that handle an action/interactivity that is unrelated to a form on the page itself. If it sends a form it should be type="submit" and if it resets a form it should be type="reset". If it is a link to a different page it should be an <a href=""> element styled as a button, as was said above.

Answer (score 0):

We are speaking about this section:

```
        <button onclick="window.location.href='inscription.html'">S'inscrire</button>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='connexion.html'">Se connecter</button>
```

If your pages are at registration.html and login.html, then you will need to change the link you reidrect to to use the appropriate name (instead of inscription.html and connexion.html). Furthermore, you will need to make sure that you try to reach them in the correct folder.

If they are to redirect to a different folder fomr your connection page, then you will need to either define their relative URL or prepend a "/" to the path to start off from the base URL.

You will also need to make sure that those pages actually work, so you will not have privilege issues or page crashes.